# SQL Server join two tables with there own values and dates kept

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, sql-date-functions

I have two queries which get me two sets of results:

Time Query:

```
SELECT a.AID AID, CONCAT(CONVERT(date, c.CDate),DATEPART(HOUR, c.CDate)) CDateHour, SUM(c.time/60/1000) duration
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON b.bkey = a.akey
LEFT JOIN TableC c ON b.subbkey = c.subckey
WHERE a.AID = '10000'
GROUP BY c.CDate, a.AID
ORDER BY c.CDate;
```

Time Results:

```
AID     CDateHour    duration
10000   2018-10-259  91
10000   2018-10-2512 25
10000   2018-10-2513 25
10000   2018-10-2514 14
10000   2018-10-2515 20
```

Count Query:

```
SELECT a.AID AID, CONCAT(CONVERT(date, d.DDate),DATEPART(HOUR, d.DDate)) DDateHour, COUNT(DISTINCT e.EID) COUNTEID
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableD d ON d.dto = a.AID
INNER JOIN TableE e ON e.ekey = d.dkey
WHERE a.AID = '10000'
GROUP BY d.DDate, a.AID
ORDER BY d.DDate
```

Count Results:

```
AID     DDateHour    COUNTEID
10000   2018-10-256  2
10000   2018-10-257  28
10000   2018-10-258  44
10000   2018-10-259  22
10000   2018-10-2510 49
10000   2018-10-2511 46
10000   2018-10-2512 37
```

I want to join these two queries to have an output of:

```
AID     DateHour      duration  COUNTID
10000   2018-10-256             2
10000   2018-10-257             28
10000   2018-10-258             44   
10000   2018-10-259   91        22
10000   2018-10-2510            49
10000   2018-10-2511            46
10000   2018-10-2512  25        37
10000   2018-10-2513  25
10000   2018-10-2514  14
10000   2018-10-2515  20
```

The blanks can either be `NULL` or `0`.

Comment: How are those "dates"? Months only have between 28-31 days, not 256+.

Comment: @Larnu They are DateHours, as per the query and alias

Comment: Concatting `day of month` with `hour of day` in this way is a recipe for disaster. How do you distinguish "day 11 and hour 1" -> **`111`** from "day 1 and hour 11" -> **`111`** ?

Comment: @PeterB Good point, I did this by: `CONCAT(CONVERT(date, d.DDate), ' ',DATEPART(HOUR, d.DDate))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
with q1 as (<first query here without order by>),
     q2 as (<second query without order by>)
select coalesce(q1.AID, q2.AID) as AID,
       coalesce(q1.DDateHour, q2.DDateHour) as DDateHour,
       q1.duration, q2.counteid
from q1 full join
     q2
     on q1.AID = q2.AID and
        q1.DDateHour = q2.DDateHour;
```